# Why extra subquery needed for filtering out where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

First of all. Sorry for the vague title. I couldn't figure out how to frame it. With the sample code, I hope you can understand my doubt.

The task was to find out the top three facilities in a club in terms of revenue generated.
I thought this is the final code.

```
 SELECT x,y as rank
    FROM tableA
 where rank <=3;
```

But this says the rank column doesn't exist. So I have to include this in another subquery to filter the top 3 ranks.

```
 SELECT x,rank
    FROM
 (SELECT x,y as rank
    FROM tableA
 ) as sub
 where rank<=3;
```

Why? I need one extra subquery? Why can't it filter using where clause in the original query?

Code for  Facility names, and their rank by revenue:

```
select res.name,rank() over(order by total desc) as rank
    from
(select fac.facid,fac.name,sum(slots*
                case
                    when memid=0 then guestcost
                    else membercost
                    end) as total
    from cd.bookings bks
    inner join cd.facilities fac
        on bks.facid=fac.facid
    group by fac.facid
order by total desc) as res
```

What I thought would work:

```
select res.name,rank() over(order by total desc) as rank
    from
(select fac.facid,fac.name,sum(slots*
                case
                    when memid=0 then guestcost
                    else membercost
                    end) as total
    from cd.bookings bks
    inner join cd.facilities fac
        on bks.facid=fac.facid
    group by fac.facid
order by total desc) as res
where rank<=3;           

     (why this don't work??)
```

What works :

```
select name, rank
    from
(select res.name,rank() over(order by total desc) as rank
    from
(select fac.facid,fac.name,sum(slots*
                case
                    when memid=0 then guestcost
                    else membercost
                    end) as total
    from cd.bookings bks
    inner join cd.facilities fac
        on bks.facid=fac.facid
    group by fac.facid
order by total desc) as res) as sub
where rank <=3;
```

Comment: The reason why the first query is not working is because you are using window function directly in the where clause, which is not allowed. But, in the last query , you are doing the ranking within a subquery.

Comment: You simply can't use a column alias in the WHERE clause on the same level. This is how the SQL syntax was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your first version of the query:

```sql
SELECT x, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY y) rnk
FROM tableA
WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

This is not legitimate, because you can't use aliases in the `WHERE` clause which were defined in a `SELECT` at the same level.  The issue here is that window functions execute generally execute *last*, before the filtering in the `WHERE` clause happens.  Instead, you need to compute the rank in a subquery and then filter on it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT x, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY y) rnk
    FROM tableA
) t
WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

Note that some versions of SQL do allow window functions to be used in a `QUALIFY` clause:

```sql
SELECT x, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY y) rnk
FROM tableA
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY y) <= 3;
```

But Postgres does not support `QUALIFY`, so the subquery option is what you will likely have to use.